# Execute bash script from Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, bash

I am trying to write a python script that will execute a bash script I have on my Windows machine. Up until now I have been using the Cygwin terminal so executing the bash script RunModels.scr has been as easy as `./RunModels.scr`. Now I want to be able to utilize `subprocess` of Python, but because Windows doesn't have the built in functionality to handle bash I'm not sure what to do.

I am trying to emulate `./RunModels.scr < validationInput > validationOutput`

I originally wrote this:

```
os.chdir(atm)
vin = open("validationInput", 'r')
vout = open("validationOutput", 'w')
subprocess.call(['./RunModels.scr'], stdin=vin, stdout=vout, shell=True)
vin.close()
vout.close()
os.chdir(home)
```

But after spending a while trying to figure out why my access was denied, I realized my issue wasn't the file permissions but the fact that I was trying to execute a bash file on Windows in general. Can someone please explain how to execute a bash script with directed input/output on windows using a python script?

Edit **(Follow up Question)**:

Thanks for the responses, I needed the full path to my bash.exe as the first param. Now however, command line calls from within RunModels.scr come back in the python output as `command not found`. For example, `ls`, `cp`, `make`. Any suggestions for this?

***Follow up #2***:
I updated my call to this:

`subprocess.call(['C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe', '-l', 'RunModels.scr'], stdin=vin, stdout=vout, cwd='C:\\path\\dir_where_RunModels\\')`

The error I now get is `/usr/bin/bash: RunModels.scr: No such file or directory`.
Using cwd does not seem to have any effect on this error, either way the subprocess is looking in `/usr/bin/bash` for `RunModels.scr`.

***SELF-ANSWERED***
I needed to specify the path to RunModels.scr in the call as well as using `cwd`.

`subprocess.call(['C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe', '-l', 'C:\\path\\dir_where_RunModels\\RunModels.scr'], stdin=vin, stdout=vout, cwd='C:\\path\\dir_where_RunModels\\')`

***But another problem...***

Regardless of specifying `cwd`, the commands executed by `RunModels.scr` are throwing errors as if `RunModels.scr` is in the wrong directory. The script executes, but `cp` and `cd` throw the error `no such file or directory`. If I navigate to where `RunModels.scr` is through the command line and execute it the old fashioned way I don't get these errors.

Comment: Since it is a *bash* script, you need to call bash command explicitly: with full path using Windows path syntax.

Comment: Notice: it is better to use `with` statements when you open files. That way you prevent to leave them opened when an exception is raised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Python 3.4 and below

Just put `bash.exe` in first place in your list of `subprocess.call` arguments. You can remove `shell=True`, that's not necessary in this case.

```
subprocess.call(['C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe', '-l', 'RunModels.scr'], 
                 stdin=vin, stdout=vout,
                 cwd='C:\\path\\dir_where_RunModels\\')
```

Depending on how bash is installed (is it in the `PATH` or not), you might have to use the full path to the bash executable.

#### Python 3.5 and above

`subprocess.call()` has been effectively replaced by `subprocess.run()`.

```
subprocess.run(['C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe', '-l', 'RunModels.scr'], 
                 stdin=vin, stdout=vout,
                 cwd='C:\\path\\dir_where_RunModels\\')
```

**Edit:**

With regard to the second question, you might need to add the `-l` option to the shell invocation to make sure it reads all the restart command files like `/etc/profile`. I presume these files contain settings for the `$PATH` in bash.

**Edit 2:**

Add something like `pwd` to the beginning of `RunModels.scr` so you can verify that you are *really* in the right directory. Check that there is no `cd` command in the rc-files!

**Edit 3:**

The error `/usr/bin/bash: RunModels.scr: No such file or directory` can also be generated if bash cannot find one of the commands that are called in the script. Try adding the `-v` option to bash to see if that gives more info.

Comment: You must give the full path to bash (for instance `c:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe`) unless it is in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the full path and the execution worked. I have updated the post with a follow up question if you can help with that too :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far. I've updated my post again. Now all the commands and scripts are recognized and executing, but behaving as if `RunModels.scr` is in the wrong directory. Using `cwd` in the call doesn't fix the problem in my case for some reason.

Comment: @RolandSmith I am starting to think my error `/usr/bin/bash: RunModels.scr: No such file or directory` is perhaps caused by bash and not `RunModels.scr`. I have added `pwd`s and checked for `cd`s with no luck. I think this is still a Windows bash issue. `RunModels.scr` has `#!/bin/bash` up top and this worked when using `./`. I have tried changing this to `#!/usr/bin/bash` `#!/usr/bin/env bash/` and none have worked while running from the python script. Do you have thoughts on this being a bash issue?

Comment: @WhS4 The `#!`-line is only used on UNIX-like operating systems. And when you call bash directly, it doesn't matter at all. See also **edit 3**.

Comment: The argument to `env` should be `bash`, not `bash/`; but it only works if `bash` (or on Windows, `bash.exe` and/or `bash.cmd` and/or etc) is on your `PATH` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution than the accepted answer is to use the `executable` keyword argument to specify the path to your shell. Behind the curtain, Python does something like

```
exec([executable, '-c`, subprocess_arg_string])
```

So, concretely, in this case,

```
subprocess.call(
    './RunModels.scr',
    stdin=vin, stdout=vout,
    shell=True,
    executable="C:/cygwin64/bin/bash.exe")
```

(Windows thankfully lets you use forward slashes instead of backslashes, so you can avoid the requirement to double the backslashes or use a raw string.)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on Windows

```py
result = subprocess.run(
    ["bash", "-c", "./mysql2sqlite.sh temp.sql"],
    capture_output=True,
).stdout.decode("utf-8")
```

with git-for-Windows' `bash` in the Windows system path.