# Windows: Unable to run a shell script in spyder (python 3.8). Invalid Syntax error

Tags: python, bash, spyder

I am trying to run a shell script in Spyder (Python 3.8).
I have tried the following and all this is giving me the same error - Invalid Syntax

1. `bash ./filename.sh`
2. `bash filename.sh`
3. `sh filename.sh`
4. `sh ./filename.sh`
5. `shell ./filename.sh`
6. `shell filename.sh`
7. import subprocess
   subprocess.run(.\filename.sh)
8. `source filename.sh`

[image]

9.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(filename.sh)
```

The last one gives the error:

> name 'filename' doesn't exist.

Note: I have rechecked my pwd.

Comment: But basic Linux commands such as pwd and ls are running on it, without error. How come only shell is not running?

Comment: I don't think your question contains enough details to troubleshoot this. Please [edit] to reveal your OS, how and where Bash and/or `sh` are installed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add quotes

```
subprocess.run("filename.sh")
```

Also, I would like to point out that unless you are using some package to add the syntax `bash`, `sh`, etc... you would get the syntax error since Python doesn't know what those keywords mean.

Comment: Throws error: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Comment: yes. Windows> annoconda> spyder

Comment: You can't run bash scripts natively in Windows. You would needs something like Cygwin to make that possible. Once you have a valid bash runtime environment, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41645522/3730626 to get the bash script to run.